# escaping of double quote with text type column at postgresql and json parsing via jackson

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jackson

I have the following table defined at postgresql:

```
        Column      |          Type          | Modifiers 
-----------------+------------------------+-----------
 id              | uuid                   | not null
 entity_snapshot | text                   | 
Indexes:
    "pk_id" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

I would like to store the following JSon string:

```
[ "org.test.MyUniqueId", {:   "uuid" : "f4b40050-9716-4346-bf84-8325fadd9876": } ]
```

for some testing, instead of doing this using Jackson, I try to type an SQL manually, and here is my problem - I can't seem to get ti right. 
My current attempt is:

```
insert into my_table(id,entity_snapshot) values ('d11d944e-6e78-11e1-aae1-52540015fc3f','[ \"org.test.MyUniqueId\", {:   \"uuid\" : \"f4b40050-9716-4346-bf84-8325fadd9876\": } ]');
```

Procuedure a record that looks like what I need when I select from the table, but when I try to use Jackson to parse it I get an error -

```
org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

Needless to say that if the same record is inserted via my java code , I can get it parsed and when it comes to looking at the record with human eyes, it looks the same to me. 
Can you tell me where I am wrong in my SQL insert statement?

Comment: You can use sqldump to write both rows inserted by Java and manually to text file and compare what's different with the manual insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotes inside single quotes do not need any escaping.

```
insert into my_table (id,entity_snapshot)
values 
(
   'd11d944e-6e78-11e1-aae1-52540015fc3f',
   '["org.test.MyUniqueId", {: "uuid" : "f4b40050-9716-4346-bf84-8325fadd9876": }]'
);
```

will work just fine:

```
postgres=> create table my_table (id uuid, entity_snapshot text);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 34,936 ms
postgres=> insert into my_table (id,entity_snapshot)
postgres-> values
postgres-> (
postgres(>    'd11d944e-6e78-11e1-aae1-52540015fc3f',
postgres(>    '["org.test.MyUniqueId", {: "uuid" : "f4b40050-9716-4346-bf84-8325fadd9876": }]'
postgres(> );
INSERT 0 1
Time: 18,255 ms
postgres=>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use Dollar-Quoted String Constants.
Details are here [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

In your case query should look like

```
insert into my_table(id,entity_snapshot) values ('d11d944e-6e78-11e1-aae1-52540015fc3f',$$[ "org.test.MyUniqueId", {:   "uuid" : "f4b40050-9716-4346-bf84-8325fadd9876": } ]$$);
```